# Why is that __init__ function of python doesn't have a return statement even though its a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

This may be a silly question but i am curious to know the answer.
As per official documentation, `__init__` doesn't need return statement. Any particular reason why is it that way.

```
>>> class Complex:
...     def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
...         self.r = realpart
...         self.i = imagpart
...
>>> x = Complex(3.0, -4.5)

>>> x.r, x.i
(3.0, -4.5)
```

Comment: Because `__init__()` is a special function. It is called to initialize a new class instance.

Comment: The simple "how" as opposed to "why" is that `__init__` doesn't need a `return` statement because a function without one implicitly returns `None`, which is the only value that `__init__` is allowed to return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__init__()` is not a normal function. It is a special method Python uses to customize an instance of a class. It is part of [Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__):

> Called after the instance has been created (by `__new__()`), but before it is returned to the caller[...].

As you can see from above, when you create a new instance of a class, Python first calls `__new_()` - which is also a special method - to create a new instance of the class. Then `__init__()` is called to customize the new instance.

It wouldn't make sense to return anything from `__init__()`, since the class instance is already created. In fact, Python goes as far as raising an error to prevent this:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         return 'foo'
... 
>>> A()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'str'
>>>
```

If you want to know what exactly is going on behind the scenes, [@eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) provides a nice explanation:

> To completely explain this story, you have to step back to the metaclass `__call__` method. In particular the default [`type.__call__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e9f9b042781e3cb480315860bcdf7b7d22cba0f8/Objects/typeobject.c#L737) in CPython calls `__new__` and `__init__` via their C slot functions, and it's `slot_tp_init` (defined in [Objects/typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e9f9b042781e3cb480315860bcdf7b7d22cba0f8/Objects/typeobject.c#L5828)) that enforces the return value to be None. If you use a custom metaclass that overrides `type.__call__`, it can manually call the `__new__` and `__init__` methods of the class with no restriction on what `__init__` can return -- as silly as that would be.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is called when you create a new instance of a class.

It's main use is initializing the instance variables, and it can be called only with an instance - so you can't call it before you create an instance anyways (what triggers it automatically).

For these reasons, `__init__`s have no reason to be able to return any value - it's simply not their use case.